# Data manipulation from text file c++

Tags: c++

I have some data that I need to sort into a proper format. This is a sample text file that I have wrote. It has the following `format:[Item Desc]:[Price]:[Quantity]:[Date]` and it is sorted according from the earliest date to latest date already.

```
 - BANANA:2:50:18NOV1912
 - CHOCOLATE:50:50:18NOV1912
 - GAME:10:10:21NOV1991
 - GAMEBOY:30:10:21NOV1991
 - SWEET:40:10:21NOV1991
 - CARD:1:10:21NOV1991
 - TOY:10:10:15NOV1993
```

I want to achieve this desired result whereby the **data(the item price) of the same year are merged/added together**. Hence the desired output will be:

```
 - Total Price: 52 Date: 18NOV1912
 - Total Price: 81 Date: 21NOV1991
 - Total Price: 10 Date: 15NOV1993
```

I have tried iterating over the vector containing my data but the result is undesirable as seen below. I will appreciate any guidance on this.

Undesired Output:

```
Item Matched Price: 52  Date: 18/11/1912
Item NOT Matched Price: 60  Date: 18/11/1912
Item Matched Price: 40  Date: 21/11/1991
Item Matched Price: 70  Date: 21/11/1991
Item Matched Price: 41  Date: 21/11/1991
Item NOT Matched Price: 11  Date: 21/11/1991
Item NOT Matched Price: 10  Date: 15/11/1993
```

Code:

```
double price = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < itemDescVec.size(); i++) {
   if (itemDescVec[i].dateYear == itemDescVec[i + 1].dateYear) {

      cout << "Item Matched ";
      price = itemDescVec[i].unitPrice + itemDescVec[i + 1].unitPrice;

      cout << "Price: " << price << "  Date: "
              << itemDescVec[i].dateDay << "/"
              << itemDescVec[i].dateMonth << "/" << itemDescVec[i].dateYear
              << endl;

   } else if (itemDescVec[i].dateYear != itemDescVec[i + 1].dateYear) {

      cout << "Item NOT Matched ";
      price = itemDescVec[i].unitPrice + itemDescVec[i + 1].unitPrice;

      cout << "Price: " << price << "  Date: "
              << itemDescVec[i].dateDay << "/"
              << itemDescVec[i].dateMonth << "/" << itemDescVec[i].dateYear
              << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: How about using a `std::map` using the date as a key to keep the total price?

Comment: Using `[i + 1]` you not only get undesirable results but also undefined behavior (due to invalid memory access).

Answer (score 0):

Your code just compares each value in the vector to the next one. This will not accomplish what you are looking for.

You have not provided the key piece of your code, the definition of the elements of `itemDescVec`, so I'm guessing that both `dateYear` and `unitPrice` are integers:

```
std::map<int, int> yearPrices;

for (unsigned i = 0; i < itemDescVec.size(); ++i) {
    yearPrices[itemDescVec[i].dateYear] += itemDescVec[i].unitPrice;
}
for (std::map<int,int>::iterator i = yearPrices.begin(); i != yearPrices.end(); ++i) {
    std::cout << " - Total Price: " << i->second << " Year: " << i->first << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i am beginning to see the point of using map. will try to implement it asap!